# Finding a scratch file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like a quick way to open a given scratch file.

For example. If I have a `notes.md` scratch. It does not show up using:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> then typing `notes.md`
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> then typing `notes.md`

The only way I know to find them is by choosing `Scratches` in the Project tool window as described here: [IntelliJ IDEA Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/scratches.html#d392382e122). This is painfully slow. Especially given that the whole purpose of a scratch is that it is a *quick* place to store something.

Comment: [It seems to work for me using shift + shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax04x.png)

Comment: I believe only if it is part of "recent files" but if you want to open older ones, I believe they do not show up.

Comment: You are correct, I changed the recent file limit to 0 and it didn't show anymore. As a poor man's workaround you could set the recent file limit to something stupidly high (`Editor` > `General` > `Limits`)

Answer (score 6):

I've run into the same problem and have tried increasing the file limit to a ridiculously high number, but I was feeling that contributed to sluggish behavior as the buffer grew.

Since then, I've discovered the Scratch plugin by dkandalov which has much better scratch file management (albeit using an entirely different implementation?).

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4428-scratch

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone comes across this thread like I did:

You can use `File` > `New` > `Import Module from Existing Sources...` on the existing directory where Intellij keeps the scratch files. This will create a "scratches" module in your project, which forces indexing of its contents. In my case, they're in `C:\Users\jacob.hanson\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\config\scratches`. You can find the full path by right clicking an existing scratch file in the project view and choosing `Show in Explorer`.

It's not the prettiest solution, but it preserves the default location of the scratches and keeps from having to increase the 'Recent File' buffer limit.

[scratch files will appear in your Shift Shift searches!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVNB9.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Search everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html#search_all) feature. Default shortcut for that is `shift+shift`